# Add Submenu items in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, nav

I am looking through tutorials and I am unable to add sub menu in my navigation bar using any of the search on google.
The code shows menu item in one line but using `<ul>` and `<li>` tag, also I am unable to show any submenu item when hovering using mouse Here is my code.

```css
/*Start of styling of navigation bar style header for large screens*/
    #nav-bar{
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      color: #333!important;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      padding: 16px;
      padding-bottom: 12px;
      font-size: 14px;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    #nav-bar .col-sm-12{
      text-align: center;
    }
    #nav-bar a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #333!important;
    }
   #nav-bar .underline {
      margin-top:8px; 
  background-color: #343956; /* same as link color */
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

#nav-bar a:hover .underline {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-bar" class="container-fluid hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <div class=" col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-5 col-md-1 col-lg-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="about.html">ABOUT<span class="underline"></span></a> </div>
        <div class=" col-md-1 col-lg-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="news.html">NEWS<span class="underline"></span></a></div>
         <div class=" col-md-2 col-lg-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="principal.html">PRINCIPAL<span class="underline"></span></a></div>
       
        <div class=" col-md-1 col-lg-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a  href="">GALLERY<span class="underline"></span></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-2 col-lg-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="downloads.html">DOWNLOADS<span class="underline"></span></a></div>
        <div class=" col-md-1 col-lg-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT<span class="underline"></span></a>  </div>
      </div>  <!--Navigation Bar for large screens-->
    </div>
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: this can help you: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbars/ and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp) would help?